# Generating Random arrows in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, arrows, metapost

I would like to draw this figure :
[image]
Hence, I resort to TikZ. But, it seems to be very difficult drawing arrows precisely in TikZ with the precise locations (x,y). I have achieved this:
[image]
Here is the **MWE**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[color=gray] (1,0) rectangle (10,5);
\draw[->, line width=2pt, color=red] (2,1) -- (3,1);
\draw[->, line width=2pt, color=red] (2,2) -- (3,2.5);
\draw[->, line width=2pt, color=red] (3,2) -- (30:3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now, my question is

### How to generate arrows of random length (between 2cm and 3cm) and random inclination (if possible of random colors too like red, yellow, violet, etc.) without crossing in TikZ. Is there any function to generate Random Numbers

### Note:

If not Tikz, pstricks or MetaPost will also do. For now, Asmptote will not work because there seems an error in the execution in my system.

Comment: I appreciate you accepted my answer, but may suggest you to wait a little longer before accepting an answer? I am sure some other answers will show up.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Can you please edit your answer as the picture in my question. The spacing between arrows is much less. How to improve that?

Comment: I am afraid I don't completely understand. What do you want to change?

Comment: Please see the figure "I want to draw this:". In that, the spacing between the arrows is much. How to achieve this spacing?

Comment: I'll have to think about this. In my current answer the starting point for each arrow as well as the ending point are randomly chosen so, in its present form, it's not easy to control the spacing.

Comment: Yup that is what I was thinking that in a randomly distributed manner, how do I manipulate the arrows? Is there any other way to draw the same  diagram? @GonzaloMedina

Comment: If understand, you want to draw random (length, color, width) arrows randomly distributed over a certain area and not crossing them. Isn't it?

Comment: Then I'd suggest to rephrase your question. Answerers didn't understood `not crossing` restriction because it was not there.

Comment: @Ignasi done. Please see the edit

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Updated version (without crossing):

A possibility with random colors, widths, directions, lengths; the image was produced using

```
\RandArrow

\def\Columns{10}
\RandArrow[80]
```

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\def\maxArrow{30}
\def\Columns{6}

\newcommand\randomarrow{
  \pgfmathsetseed{\pdfuniformdeviate 10000000}
  \edef\R{\pdfuniformdeviate 255}
  \edef\G{\pdfuniformdeviate 255}
  \edef\B{\pdfuniformdeviate 255}
  \xdefinecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{\R,\G,\B}
  \tikz\draw[->,line width=2pt*rnd+1pt,color=mycolor] 
    (rnd,rnd) -- ++(rnd*360:rnd+0.2);
}
\newcommand\RandArrow[1][30]{%
  \def\maxArrow{#1}  
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach [count=\i] \val in {1,...,\maxArrow} 
  { 
    \path  
      let \n{row}={int(mod(\i -1, \Columns))}, 
            \n{col}={ int( ( \i - 1 ) / (-\Columns) ) } 
      in 
         (\n{row}, \n{col}) rectangle  +(1,1) 
         +(0.5, 0.5) node{\randomarrow};
  }
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \draw[orange!70!black,line width=1pt,fill=yellow!15]
    (current bounding box.north west)
      rectangle
    (current bounding box.south east);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\RandArrow

\def\Columns{10}
\RandArrow[80]

\end{document}
```

The idea to avoid crossing arrows is to have a grid and place each arrow in one of the squares of the grid.

1. `\maxArrows` allows to specify the number of arrows (initially set to `30`).
2. `\Columns` controls the number of rows of the grid (initially set to `6`).
3. `\randomarrow` draws an arrow; the width, length, color and direction are chosen randomly using `rnd`; the length will only be (in the worst case) `0.2cm` larger than the width of the square; this is to prevent arrows from having zero length.
4. The main command is `\RandArrow` with an optional argument allowing to decide the number of arrows to be drawn; the default value is `30`.
5. As suggested by **Paul Gaborit** in [`his answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179753/3954), `\pgfmathsetseed{\pdfuniformdeviate 10000000}` was used in the definition of `\randomarrow` to change the seed used by the pseudo-random generator at each compilation.

Introducing some randomness in the grid gives better results:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\def\maxArrow{30}
\def\Columns{6}

\newcommand\randomarrow{
  \pgfmathsetseed{\pdfuniformdeviate 10000000}
  \edef\R{\pdfuniformdeviate 255}
  \edef\G{\pdfuniformdeviate 255}
  \edef\B{\pdfuniformdeviate 255}
  \xdefinecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{\R,\G,\B}
  \tikz\draw[->,line width=2pt*rnd+1pt,color=mycolor] 
    (rnd,rnd) -- ++(rnd*360:rnd+0.1);
}
\newcommand\RandArrow[1][30]{%
  \pgfmathsetseed{\pdfuniformdeviate 10000000}
  \def\maxArrow{#1}  
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach [count=\i] \val in {1,...,\maxArrow} 
  { 
    \path  
      let \n{row}={ int(mod(\i -1, \Columns))}, 
            \n{col}={ int( ( \i - 1 ) / (-\Columns) ) } 
      in 
         (\n{row}, \n{col}) rectangle  +({random(2,3)},rand) 
         node[near start] {\randomarrow};
  }
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \draw[orange!70!black,line width=1pt,fill=yellow!15]
    (current bounding box.north west)
      rectangle
    (current bounding box.south east);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\RandArrow

\def\Columns{10}
\RandArrow[80]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to be sure. Is there any difference between using `\pgfmathparse{random()}  \pgfmathsetmacro\xpos{\width*\pgfmathresult}` or just `\width*rnd` instead of `\xpos`?

Comment: @Ignasi since I didn't use any arguments to `random()`, they should be equivalent.

Comment: @Ignasi now I edited my answer using arguments for some of the `random` and now `rnd` and `random(2,3)` behave differently.

Comment: Gonzalo I wanted to be sure because I didn't understand why was so much typping needed ;-)

Comment: Please see the edited question @GonzaloMedina

Comment: @Ignasi you're right. In fact, I just edited my answer saving some typing.

Comment: @subhamsoni With your edit and the restriction of "not crossing", my answer is useless. I'll delete it.

Comment: @subhamsoni Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Awesome... have no words to express :)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina can you do 1 small favour. Can you please surround it in a box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14679/discussion-between-subham-soni-and-gonzalo-medina).

Answer (score 11):

### Edit: random non crossing arrows

Here is a very simple solution (using a grid placement) with random colors, random lengths and random directions.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\pgfmathsetseed{\pdfuniformdeviate 10000000}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[black] (0.5,0.5) rectangle (10.5,10.5);
  \foreach \x in {1,...,10} {
    \foreach \y in {1,...,10} {
      % random HSB color definition
      \pgfmathsetmacro\hue{rnd}
      \definecolor{mycolor}{rgb:hsb}{\hue,1,1}
      % random direction and length
      \pgfmathsetmacro\angle{rnd*360}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\halflen{rnd*.3+0.2}
      % arrow
      \draw[line width=2pt,-stealth,color=mycolor]
        (\x,\y) +(\angle:-\halflen) -- +(\angle:\halflen);
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### First version: random arrows

Here is a possible solution.

The `rnd` function generates a pseudo-random number between 0 and 1. Thus:

- `(rnd*4+3,rnd*4+3)` gives a random coordinate between `(3,3)` and `(7,7)`.
- `++(rnd*360:rnd*2+1)` moves the previous coordinate in any direction (`rnd*360`) with a length between 1cm and 3cm.

The `random` function used with two arguments x and y generates  a random integer between x and y. Thus:

- `\pgfmathtruncatemacro\numcolor{random(0,3)}` sets `\numcolor` with a random integer between 0 and 3.

To change the seed used by pseudo-random generator at each compilation, you may use (with `pdflatex`) `\pgfmathsetseed{\pdfuniformdeviate 10000000}` in your peamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\pgfmathsetseed{\pdfuniformdeviate 10000000}
\tikzset{
  my arrow/.style={-latex,line width=2},
  my arrow 0/.style={my arrow,color=red},
  my arrow 1/.style={my arrow,color=violet},
  my arrow 2/.style={my arrow,color=yellow},
  my arrow 3/.style={my arrow,color=black},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw[color=gray!50] (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
  \foreach \num in {1,...,20} {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\numcolor{random(0,3)}
    \draw[my arrow \numcolor] (rnd*4+3,rnd*4+3) -- ++(rnd*360:rnd*2+1);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

Random and not grid-aligned arrows, using the code from [tikz: Distribute evenly and randomly circles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87497/tikz-distribute-evenly-and-randomly-circles):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\def\xlist{4}
\def\ylist{4}

\newcommand{\fillrandomly}[4]{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\diameter{#3*2}
    \draw (0-#3,0-#3) rectangle (#1+#3,#2+#3);
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#4}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\x{rnd*#1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\y{rnd*#2}
        \xdef\collision{0}
        \foreach \element [count=\i] in \xlist{
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\i-1}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\checkdistance{ sqrt( ({\xlist}[\j]-(\x))^2 + ({\ylist}[\j]-(\y))^2 ) }
            \ifdim\checkdistance pt<\diameter pt
                \xdef\collision{1}
                \breakforeach
            \fi
        }
        \ifnum\collision=0
            \xdef\xlist{\xlist,\x}
            \xdef\ylist{\ylist,\y}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\randomvalue{rnd*360}
            \draw [red, line width=4pt, -latex] (\x,\y) +(\randomvalue:-#3) -- +(\randomvalue:#3);
        \fi 

    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetseed{2}
\fillrandomly{7.5}{5}{0.5}{100}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where is the random length? :-)

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer: Adding random length, thickness, colour, arrowhead, curvature, etc. is trivial, so it does not need to be explicitly stated in the answer.

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add,multido}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-6,-6)(6,6)
\pstVerb{ realtime srand }% For different output of every run
\psframe[linecolor=black!15](-5,-5)(5,5)
\multido{\iRow=-4+1}{9}{%
  \multido{\iCol=-4+1}{9}{%
    \rput{!Rand 360 mul}(\iRow,\iCol){%
      \pscustom{%
        \arrows{->}
        \code{Rand Rand Rand setrgbcolor 
           0 Rand 32 mul dup neg 0 exch ArrowB moveto 
           lineto Rand 2 mul setlinewidth stroke}}}}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please see the edited question @Herbert

Answer (score 7):

A try with MetaPost, using its handy *uniformdeviate()* random function, which generates a random number between 0 and the number specified in argument. The generated vectors are of random-generated origin, direction and length (between 2 cm and 3 cm), they can't be too close to each other thanks to a *bb* macro which puts a given vector into a "bounding box" and checks with the *intersectiontimes* function if they don't intersect, and they are of random colors in the RGB specification.

```
u := 1cm; % unit length
nb_vectors := 20; wd = .5; 
boolean intersect; pair random_origin; color random_color; path candidate, random_vector[], bb_candidate, bb[];
%
vardef bb(expr p) =
  save orig, extr; pair orig, extr; orig = point 0 of p; extr = point 1 of p;
  pair v,w; v = wd*unitvector(extr-orig)*u; w = v rotated 90;
  (orig - v + w) -- (extr + v + w) -- (extr + v - w) -- (orig - v - w) -- cycle
enddef;
%
beginfig(1);
  pickup pencircle scaled 2bp;
  i = 1; 
  forever: 
    exitunless (i <=  nb_vectors);
    intersect := false;
    random_length := u*(2+uniformdeviate(1));
    random_angle := uniformdeviate(359);
    random_origin := u*(uniformdeviate(wd*nb_vectors), uniformdeviate(wd*nb_vectors));
    random_color := (uniformdeviate(1), uniformdeviate(1), uniformdeviate(1));
    candidate := random_origin -- (random_origin + random_length*dir(random_angle));
    j := 1;
    forever:
      exitif (j = i) or (intersect = true);
      if bb(random_vector[j]) intersectiontimes bb(candidate) <>  (-1, -1):
        intersect := true;
      fi;
      j := j+1;
    endfor;
    if intersect = false: 
      random_vector[i] = candidate;
      drawarrow candidate withcolor random_color;
      i := i+1;
    fi;
  endfor;
endfig;
end.
```

Here one of the possible result:

[image]

Comment: I tried to reuse your code for representation of forces but I don't be able to add labels because a conflit with bb[] definition. Did you know a way to fix that?

Comment: Not sure if it is what you want, but I've got no conflict of any sort if I place `freelabel(btex $v$ etex, point .5 of candidate, point .5 of candidate + dir (random_angle + 90));` just after `drawarrow candidate withcolor random_color;` (the `freelabel` macro is part of the Metafun format).

Comment: In Context don't work.! Declared variable conflicts with previous vardef.
<to be read again> 
                   ;
<*> ...idate, random_vector[], bb_candidate, bb[];

Comment: I create a new question to [context] guys http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225864/metapost-error-related-with-context

Answer (score 4):

Modifying the existing PSTricks answer to be more compact, perhaps!

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}   

\pstVerb
{
  realtime srand
  /setRGBcolor /setrgbcolor load def
  /setgray { pop tx@Dict begin Rand Rand Rand end setRGBcolor } def
  /Get {8 Rand mul 4 sub} bind def
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[arrows=->](-4,-4)(4,4)
\psframe*[linecolor=black!15](-4,-4)(4,4)
\psLoop{100}{\psline(!Get Get)(!Get Get)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Animated version

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}   

\pstVerb
{
  realtime srand
  /setRGBcolor /setrgbcolor load def
  /setgray { pop tx@Dict begin Rand Rand Rand end setRGBcolor } def
    /Get {8 Rand mul 4 sub} bind def
}

\begin{document}
\psLoop{25}{%
\begin{pspicture}[arrows=->,linewidth=2pt](-4,-4)(4,4)
\psframe*[linecolor=black!15](-4,-4)(4,4)
\psLoop{25}{\psline(!Get Get)(!Get Get)}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Epilepsy warning!

Comment: Please see my edited question

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer: How can you stop the arrows from crossing?

Comment: @Jake: By increasing the frame rate so nobody can see they are actually crossing one over others. :-)