# Metapost error related with ConTeXt

Tags: context, context-mkiv, metapost

I try to reuse this code from fpast ([Generating Random arrows in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179745/generating-random-arrows-in-tikz/180111#180111)) in context but I found a error message associated with the freelabel() function. If I try to add the labels with label() function  or by "**draw textext()**" method I found the same error. I think that this error is related to context side.

> ! Declared variable conflicts with previous vardef.
>
> ```
>                ; <*> ...idate, random_vector[], bb_candidate, bb[];
>                                                vardef bb(expr p) = save ...
> ```
>
> ! Inconsistent equation (off by -20).  
>                      ; <*> ...enddef; pickup pencircle scaled 2bp; i = 1;
>                                                      forever: exitunless (i <=...

```
\starttext

\startMPcode
numeric u, nb_vectors, wd;
u := 1cm; % unit length
nb_vectors := 20; wd = .5; 
boolean intersect; pair random_origin; color random_color; path candidate, random_vector[], bb_candidate, bb[];
%
vardef bb(expr p) =
  save orig, extr; pair orig, extr; orig = point 0 of p; extr = point 1 of p;
  pair v,w; v = wd*unitvector(extr-orig)*u; w = v rotated 90;
  (orig - v + w) -- (extr + v + w) -- (extr + v - w) -- (orig - v - w) -- cycle
enddef;
%

  pickup pencircle scaled 2bp;
  i = 1; 
  forever: 
    exitunless (i <=  nb_vectors);
    intersect := false;
    random_length := u*(2+uniformdeviate(1));
    random_angle := uniformdeviate(359);
    random_origin := u*(uniformdeviate(wd*nb_vectors), uniformdeviate(wd*nb_vectors));
    random_color := (uniformdeviate(1), uniformdeviate(1), uniformdeviate(1));
    candidate := random_origin -- (random_origin + random_length*dir(random_angle));
    j := 1;
    forever:
      exitif (j = i) or (intersect = true);
      if bb(random_vector[j]) intersectiontimes bb(candidate) <>  (-1, -1):
        intersect := true;
      fi;
      j := j+1;
    endfor;
    if intersect = false: 
      random_vector[i] = candidate;
      drawarrow candidate withcolor random_color;
      freelabel(btex $v$ etex, point .5 of candidate, point .5 of candidate + dir (random_angle + 90));
      i := i+1;
    fi;
  endfor;
\stopMPcode


\stoptext
```

Comment: Compiling just the Metapost code loading `metafun` runs without errors.

Comment: You are right. I think that error is related with ConTeXt definitions.

Comment: Please don't post the same question simultaneously at the context mailing list and on this site. Pick one, and if you don't get a response within a reasonable time, only then post on the other.

Comment: I'm sorry for that.
I have not posted simultaneously. In StackExchange I posted yesterday, in the the mailing list I posted this morning.
Usually I go first to the mailing list for help,  but this piece of code is not mine and for that I decided to ask for help in StackExchange (where the code was first introduced by fpast).
However, despite fpast efforts, to whom I am very grateful, the error persisted. Hence I have decided to ask to mailing list.

Answer (score 4):

Removing the path variable `bb[]` (which is not used in the following code anyway, certainly a relic of my first attempts on this subject) makes it work with ConTeXt-MKIV. Maybe it was conflict detected with the `bb()` macro defined just after. But in this case, I've no idea about why it did work with direct MetaFun and not with ConTeXt.

Replace thus

```
 path candidate, random_vector[], bb_candidate, bb[];
```

by

```
path candidate, random_vector[] ;
```

(the `bb_candidate` path variable is of no use either).

Results:

[image]

**EDIT** I've just checked: while it works well now with ConTeXt-MKIV, it still doesn't work with ConTeXt-MKII. I'm at a loss for guessing why, since I'm not a regular ConTeXt user.

**EDIT (bis)** It seems that the actual reason it works now (at least with ConTeXt-MKIV) is that I've replaced the equation `i = 1` by an assignment `i := 1`. See the comments below. I would suppose that the `i` variable is already defined somewhere else in ConTeXt-Metafun… But it still does not work with ConTeXt-MKII anyway. (No more error in that case, but the picture does not appear.)

Comment: I have no luck . Still does not work. ConTeXt  ver: 2015.01.23 22:11 MKIV beta  fmt: 2015.1.25  int: english/english >
system          > 'cont-new.mkiv' loaded

Comment: I just saw it did not work either with another installation (Mac OS X 10.8 instead of Mac OS X 10.10)… Seems that I've found the actual culprit: the `i = 1` equation. Replace it by `i := 1` or `numeric i ; i = 1`, and it works fine again with ConTeXt-MKIV, at least in my TeX installation. But it still doesn't work with ConTeXt-MKII, and I've still no idea about why this equation had to be replaced by an assignment, since the equation worked well with direct Metafun… Any ConTeXt wizard here?

Comment: I found the same solution by Hans Hagen: i := 1 ; % never assume variable is not set global (such is mp)

Comment: Thanks again.There is a guy who successfully compiled this code mkii. He said:Interestingly it seems to work in mkii, probably because mkii calls external metafun:

context --pdftex --passon=--shell-escape test.tex

Comment: @Jorge - the variable scope design is quite deliberate! And generally very effective. If you want local variables put them inside a `begingroup`, `endgroup` pair, and use `save` to protect the outside value.