# Drawing stones and pebbles under seafloor

Tags: tikz-pgf, random, clip

in order to do some technical drawings, I intend to reproduced a (schematized) pebbled sea floor. I could manage to do a MWE, but this is as far as I can possibly get.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{%
decorations.pathreplacing,%
decorations.pathmorphing%
}
\newcommand\irregularcircle[1]{% radius, irregularity
  let \n1 = {(#1)+rand*(0.1*#1)} in
  +(0:\n1)
  \foreach \a in {10,20,...,350}{
    let \n1 = {(#1)+rand*(0.2*#1)} in
    -- +(\a:\n1)
  } -- cycle
}

 \begin{document}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
                media/.style={font={\footnotesize\sffamily}},
                wave/.style={
                decorate,decoration={snake,post length=1.4mm,amplitude=2mm,
                segment length=2mm},thick},
                interface/.style={
                % The border decoration is a path replacing decorator. 
                % For the interface style we want to draw the original path.
                % The postaction option is therefore used to ensure that the
                % border decoration is drawn *after* the original path.
                    postaction={draw,decorate,decoration={border,angle=-135,
                    amplitude=0.3cm,segment length=2mm}}
                }
                ]
 \begin{scope}
  \draw [draw=none, fill=cyan!10, rounded corners=2mm] (-2,0) rectangle 
   (10,2);  
    \draw [interface, thick, black] (-2,0)--(10,0);
    \draw[draw=none, fill=brown!10, rounded corners=1mm, opacity=0.5] 
     (-2,0)rectangle (10,-1);
      \clip (-2,0) rectangle (10,-2);
      \foreach \a in {0,1,...,100}
       { 
          \draw[black!50,ultra thin,rounded corners=.5mm, fill=brown!20] 
              (8*rand, rand) \irregularcircle{0.21cm}; 

        } 
     \end{scope} 
     \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

Now, i have following questions:

1. any better way to draw stones (I used an available function on tikz to draw circle with addded noise)
2. How could I (equally?) distribute the stones below the water? Ideally bounded between xmin,xmax AND ymin, ymax

Thank you! 
Marco

Comment: Alas, there are no built in patterns for this. I would use clip art and crop it to shape (tikz \clip, not \includgraphics [view=...]).

Comment: OTOH, it might be less expensive to create your own clip art.  FREE CLIP ART (only $12/image).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another two options, first using `\pgfdeclarepatternformonly` within tikzpicture environment to enable to use basic tikz code instructions like `\draw` instead `\pgfpath...`, the issue is that only accept paths, so filling with shades is not available; for this reason the second option is done using basic tikz code in drawing definitions to not repeat the code many times and creating another definition like a `pattern` helped with `clip` and `foreach` statement.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,shapes.geometric,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    myshade/.style={
        black!50,
        draw,
        ultra thin,
        rounded corners=.5mm,
        top color=brown!20,
        bottom color=brown!20!gray
    },
    interface/.style={
                % The border decoration is a path replacing decorator. 
                % For the interface style we want to draw the original path.
                % The postaction option is therefore used to ensure that the
                % border decoration is drawn *after* the original path.
                    postaction={draw,decorate,decoration={border,angle=-135,
                    amplitude=0.3cm,segment length=2mm}}
       }
    ]
    \def\stone(#1)[#2][#3]{%Drawing manually some shape
        \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},rotate=#2,scale=#3,transform shape]
            \draw[line width=0.25pt,rounded corners=1pt]
                (15:3pt) -- (45:4pt) -- (89:5pt)--(135:6pt) -- (150:3pt) -- (182:4pt)--(235:6pt) -- (280:3pt) -- (330:2pt) -- cycle;

        \end{scope}
    }
    %Declare a new pattern ¿form only?
    \pgfdeclarepatternformonly{pebless under sea floor}{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}{\pgfqpoint{15pt}{15pt}}{\pgfqpoint{15pt}{15pt}}%
    {
         \stone(8pt,6pt)[-15][1]
         \stone(0pt,0pt)[45][0.7]
         \stone(15pt,15pt)[45][0.7]
         \stone(0pt,15pt)[45][0.7]
         \stone(15pt,0pt)[45][0.7]
         \stone(0pt,7.5pt)[180][0.7]
         \stone(15pt,7.5pt)[180][0.7]
         \stone(7.5pt,0pt)[90][0.7]
         \stone(7.5pt,15pt)[90][0.7]
         \draw[line width=0.25pt,rotate=-45] (5.5pt,10pt) ellipse (1pt and 2pt);
         \draw[line width=0.25pt] (12pt,10pt) circle (0.7pt);
    }
    %Create a second shape to create a brute force pattern...
    \def\stone2(#1)[#2][#3]{
        \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},rotate=#2,scale=#3,transform shape]
            \draw[myshade]
                (15:3pt) -- (45:4pt) -- (89:5pt)--(135:6pt) -- (150:3pt) -- (182:4pt)--(235:6pt) -- (280:3pt) -- (330:2pt) -- cycle;
        \end{scope}
    }
    \def\stonepattern(#1){%Brute force pattern
        \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}]
            \clip (0,0) rectangle ++(15pt,15pt);
            \stone2(8pt,6pt)[-15][1]
            \stone2(0pt,0pt)[45][0.7]
            \stone2(15pt,15pt)[45][0.7]
            \stone2(0pt,15pt)[45][0.7]
            \stone2(15pt,0pt)[45][0.7]
            \stone2(0pt,7.5pt)[180][0.7]
            \stone2(15pt,7.5pt)[180][0.7]
            \stone2(7.5pt,0pt)[90][0.7]
            \stone2(7.5pt,15pt)[90][0.7]
         \draw[line width=0.25pt,rotate=-45,myshade] (5.5pt,10pt) ellipse (1pt and 2pt);
         \draw[line width=0.25pt,myshade] (12pt,10pt) circle (0.7pt);
        \end{scope}
    }

    %Start drawing the thing
    \clip[rounded corners=0.2cm] (0,2) rectangle ++(12,-3);
    \fill [cyan!10] (0,0) rectangle ++(12,2);
    \fill[fill=brown!25, rounded corners=1mm, opacity=0.5] 
    (0,0) rectangle ++(12,-1);
    %Drawing sea floor using pattern
    \fill[pattern=pebless under sea floor] (0,0) rectangle ++(6,-1);
    %Dragind sea floor using brute force...
    \begin{scope}
        \clip(6,0) rectangle ++(6,-1);
        \foreach \x in {0,...,11}{
            \foreach \y in{0,...,2}{
                \stonepattern(6cm+\x*15pt,-1cm+\y*15pt)
            }
        }
    \end{scope}
    \draw [thick, black,interface] (0,0)--(13,0);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many compliments for your work. Very nice and I have upvoted all users.

Comment: J Leon V.,  this is very close to what I had in mind. Thank you. As a next step I want now to draw an up-sloping bed. I will try to do it and post it here to get some more feedback.

Answer (score 8):

Conceptually the problem of drawing the stones is very similar to what has been done in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87518/121799), which I am recycling here. This allows you to avoid overlaps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{%
decorations.pathreplacing,%
decorations.pathmorphing%
}
\newcommand\irregularcircle[1]{% radius, irregularity
  +(0:#1)
  \foreach \a in {30,60,...,330}{
    let \n1 = {(#1)+rand*(0.2*#1)} in
    -- +(\a:\n1)
  } -- cycle
}
%from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87518/121799
\def\xlist{4}
\def\ylist{4}
\newcommand{\fillrandomly}[7][]{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\diameter{#6*2}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#7}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\x{0.5*(#4+#2+(2*rnd-1)*(#4-#2))}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\y{0.5*(#5+#3+(2*rnd-1)*(#5-#3))}
        \xdef\collision{0}
        \foreach \element [count=\i] in \xlist{
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\i-1}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\checkdistance{ sqrt( ({\xlist}[\j]-(\x))^2 + ({\ylist}[\j]-(\y))^2 ) }
            \ifdim\checkdistance pt<\diameter pt
                \xdef\collision{1}
                \breakforeach
            \fi
        }
        \ifnum\collision=0
            \xdef\xlist{\xlist,\x}
            \xdef\ylist{\ylist,\y}
             \draw[black!50,ultra thin,rounded corners=.5mm, 
             top color=brown!20,bottom color=brown!20!gray,
             shading angle={(0.5+rand)*20}] 
              (\x,\y) \irregularcircle{0.21cm};
        \fi 

    }
}


 \begin{document}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
                media/.style={font={\footnotesize\sffamily}},
                wave/.style={
                decorate,decoration={snake,post length=1.4mm,amplitude=2mm,
                segment length=2mm},thick},
                interface/.style={
                % The border decoration is a path replacing decorator. 
                % For the interface style we want to draw the original path.
                % The postaction option is therefore used to ensure that the
                % border decoration is drawn *after* the original path.
                    postaction={draw,decorate,decoration={border,angle=-135,
                    amplitude=0.3cm,segment length=2mm}}
                }
                ]
 \begin{scope}
  \draw [draw=none, fill=cyan!10, rounded corners=2mm] (-2,0) rectangle 
   (10,2);  
    \draw [interface, thick, black] (-2,0)--(10,0);
    \draw[draw=none, fill=brown!10, rounded corners=1mm, opacity=0.5] 
     (-2,0)rectangle (10,-1);
      \clip (-2,0) rectangle (10,-2);
      \fillrandomly{-2+0.21}{-0.21}{10-0.21}{-1+0.21}{0.21}{37}
     \end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for your second question: do you have a rough idea how the stones should look like? I made a proposal but it may be very different from what you're hoping to get.

It might be nicer to have the stones on the background.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{%
decorations.pathreplacing,%
decorations.pathmorphing
}
\newcommand\irregularcircle[1]{% radius, irregularity
  +(0:#1)
  \foreach \a in {30,60,...,330}{
    let \n1 = {(#1)+rand*(0.2*#1)} in
    -- +(\a:\n1)
  } -- cycle
}
%from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87518/121799
\def\xlist{4}
\def\ylist{4}
\newcommand{\fillrandomly}[7][]{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\diameter{#6*2}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#7}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\x{0.5*(#4+#2+(2*rnd-1)*(#4-#2))}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\y{0.5*(#5+#3+(2*rnd-1)*(#5-#3))}
        \xdef\collision{0}
        \foreach \element [count=\i] in \xlist{
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\i-1}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\checkdistance{ sqrt( ({\xlist}[\j]-(\x))^2 + ({\ylist}[\j]-(\y))^2 ) }
            \ifdim\checkdistance pt<\diameter pt
                \xdef\collision{1}
                \breakforeach
            \fi
        }
        \ifnum\collision=0
            \xdef\xlist{\xlist,\x}
            \xdef\ylist{\ylist,\y}
             \draw[black!50,ultra thin,rounded corners=.5mm, 
             top color=brown!20,bottom color=brown!20!gray,
             shading angle={(0.5+rand)*20}] 
              (\x,\y) \irregularcircle{0.21cm};
        \fi 

    }
}


 \begin{document}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
                media/.style={font={\footnotesize\sffamily}},
                wave/.style={
                decorate,decoration={snake,post length=1.4mm,amplitude=2mm,
                segment length=2mm},thick},
                interface/.style={
                % The border decoration is a path replacing decorator. 
                % For the interface style we want to draw the original path.
                % The postaction option is therefore used to ensure that the
                % border decoration is drawn *after* the original path.
                    postaction={draw,decorate,decoration={border,angle=-135,
                    amplitude=0.3cm,segment length=2mm}}
                }
                ]
  \draw [draw=none, fill=cyan!10, rounded corners=2mm] (-2,0) rectangle 
   (10,2);  
  \begin{scope}
   \clip (-2,0) rectangle (10,-2);
   \draw[draw=none, fill=brown!10, rounded corners=1mm, opacity=0.5] 
     (-2,0)rectangle (10,-1);
   \fillrandomly{-2+0.21}{-0.21}{10-0.21}{-1+0.21}{0.21}{37}
   \draw [interface, thick, black] (-2,0)--(10,0);
  \end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]