# Tikz: Animate creation of nodes in a defined rectangle/box

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations

I want to let text nodes pop-up at random positions in a defined part/box of a beamer slide automatically. Currently, I store the strings with the node texts in an array and iterate over the array using a `foreach` loop.

My issues:

- All node locations are re-calculated for each loop step. Due to `rand` in the node location already visible nodes also get new coordinates. Can I have fixed coordinates for already visible nodes?
- How do I make the `tikzpicture` use the complete right column?
- Is it possible to animate that overlay on one slide/frame by making each node visible after a certain time instead of having to click for every single overlay?

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{test}

\begin{columns}
  \begin{column}{0.39\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Some text
    \end{itemize}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
    \centering

    \def\namelist{{"test1","test2","test3","test4","test5","test6","test7"}}%

    \tikzset{%
      cloudstyle/.style={%
        cloud,
        cloud puffs=11.5,
        aspect=3,
        align=center,
        inner sep=0pt,
        draw,
        fill=lightgray,
      }%
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \foreach \i in {0,...,3} {
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\z{\i+1}
        \visible<\z->{
          \pgfmathsetmacro\mynodename{\namelist[\i]}
          \node[cloudstyle] (\mynodename) at (rand,rand) {\mynodename};
        }
      }
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

### How it could look like

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code, a list is created once and for all with a command

```
\CreateRandomCoordinateList{<list>}{<# of entries>}{<prefactor x>}{<prefactor y>}
```

The second trick is to add a bounding box to the picture since otherwise the nodes appear to jump. (One could also write a solution without a bounding box.) The following produces an animation. To have it automatically animate, use `acroread` in the full screen mode. `\transduration<2-6>{1}` indicates that there is 1 second between the steps.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,overlay-beamer-styles}
\newcommand{\CreateRandomCoordinateList}[4]{
\foreach \X in {1,...,#2}
 {\pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{rand*#3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{rand*#4}
\ifnum\X=1
 \xdef#1{(\myx,\myy)}
\else
 \xdef#1{#1,(\myx,\myy)}
\fi}    
}
\begin{document}
\CreateRandomCoordinateList{\lstRnd}{6}{2}{2}
%\typeout{\lstRnd}
\newcount\NumClouds
\begin{frame}[t]{test}
\animate<2-6>
\animatevalue<1-6>{\NumClouds}{1}{6}  
\transduration<2-6>{1}
\begin{columns}
  \begin{column}{0.39\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Some text
    \end{itemize}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
    \centering

    \edef\namelist{{"test1","test2","test3","test4","test5","test6","test7"}}%

    \tikzset{%
      cloudstyle/.style={%
        cloud,
        cloud puffs=11.5,
        aspect=3,
        align=center,
        inner sep=0pt,
        draw,
        fill=lightgray,
      }%
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \path[use as bounding box] (-1,-1) rectangle (3,3);
      \foreach \Coord [count=\z,evaluate=\z as \i using {int(\z-1)}] in
      \lstRnd {
          \pgfmathsetmacro\mynodename{\namelist[\i]}
          \ifnum\i<\NumClouds
            \node[cloudstyle] (\mynodename) at \Coord {\mynodename};
          \fi
      }
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And this is a slight variation in which I use [Jake's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87518/121799) to build a list of coordinates such that the clouds do not overlap.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,overlay-beamer-styles}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87518/121799
\def\xlist{2}
\def\ylist{2}

\newcommand{\fillrandomly}[4]{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\diameter{#3*2}
    %\draw (0,0) rectangle (#1,#2);
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#4}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\x{rnd*#1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\y{rnd*#2}
        \xdef\collision{0}
        \foreach \element [count=\i] in \xlist{
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\i-1}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\checkdistance{ sqrt( 0.25*({\xlist}[\j]-(\x))^2 + ({\ylist}[\j]-(\y))^2 ) }
            \ifdim\checkdistance pt<\diameter pt
                \xdef\collision{1}
                \breakforeach
            \fi
        }
        \ifnum\collision=0
            \xdef\xlist{\xlist,\x}
            \xdef\ylist{\ylist,\y}
            %\draw [red, thick] (\x,\y) circle [radius=#3];
        \fi 

    }
}



\begin{document}
% creates random list
\fillrandomly{6}{8}{0.6}{7}
%\typeout{xlist=\xlist,ylist=\ylist}

\begin{frame}[t]{test}

\begin{columns}
  \begin{column}{0.39\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Some text
    \end{itemize}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
    \centering

    \edef\namelist{{"test1","test2","test3","test4","test5","test6","test7"}}%

    \tikzset{%
      cloudstyle/.style={%
        cloud,
        cloud puffs=11.5,
        aspect=3,
        align=center,
        inner sep=0pt,
        draw,
        fill=lightgray,
      }%
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
      \path[use as bounding box] (-1,-1) rectangle (7,9);
      \foreach \X [count=\z,evaluate=\z as \i using {int(\z-1)}] in
      \xlist {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Y}{{\ylist}[\i]}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\mynodename{\namelist[\i]}
        %\typeout{x=\X,y=\Y,name=\mynodename}
        \node[cloudstyle,visible on=<\z->] (\mynodename) at (\X,\Y) {\mynodename};
      }
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, like that :) Thanks. I have to admit, I don't really understand how your solution works. Isn't the call to `lstRnd`recursive? Could you please give me some explanations to your solution? And also, can I animate this using `animate`? In the end, I'll have much more nodes than 7 and I do not want to click a 100 times.

Comment: @krtek I added some explanation and also improved the code in that the nodes are prevented from overlapping. Will try a bit later what can be done about animate.

Comment: Thanks. I'll get to it as soon as I can. The overlapping check is nice, but I think in my case not necessary. In the end there will be ~90 nodes, so I guess they will have to overlap to fit on a frame.

Comment: @krtek I added a version with overlapping nodes that will autoplay (provided you use acroread in fullscreen mode or something equivalent).

Comment: Thanks for the update. It works great in Acrobat Reader. However, I couldn't get it to work with SumatraPDF or Foxit Phantom. I tried using it with a string array with 90 entries. But I get an error. I guess I missed something in `CreateRandomCoordinateList`. Could you please expain the 4 arguments?

Comment: @krtek In `\CreateRandomCoordinateList{<list>}{<# of entries>}{<prefactor x>}{<prefactor y>}`, the first entry is the macro in which the list will get stored in, the second denotes the number of entries, and the last two the factors by which you stretch the x and y direction. And I do not know which viewers apart from `acroread` are supported. And it is hard to guess where the error is, I do not see what you've tried.